# Is it possible to make preference items without the possibility of interactive editing?

Tags: android

Is it possible to make the item in "preferencses.xml" that will appear as "gray" (read-only,  like "About/Version" from android main menu?) text without the possibility of interactive editing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you'd like to hard code this and only use xml:

```
<EditTextPreference
    android:key="PREF_KEY"
    android:enabled="false"
    android:selectable="false" />
```

If you'd like to be more dynamic, changing enabled-ness at runtime, you can do this in code (possibly in your settings activity's onCreate):

```
    Preference pref =
        getPreferenceScreen().findPreference("PREF_KEY");
    pref.setEnabled(false);
    pref.setSelectable(false);
```

And as hwrdprkns points out, if you don't need the dynamic route (your preference is never used as a real preference), you can use the base preference class instead of a subclass like EditTextPreference.

Comment: Ugh. This is not the way to do it.

Comment: Ugh yourself!  I didn't realize you could use the base Preference, that's pretty neat.  However, your answer didn't address the "grayed out" look and the un-selectability the OP was going for.

Comment: Also, I wasn't clear about how the above two snippets could be used separately - I've edited to be more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Use the base [Preference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/Preference.html):

```
<Preference
android:title="Custom Preference"
android:summary="This works almost like a button"
android:key="customPref" />
```